# Which "app" is responsible for "open with"

Tags: default-applications

Which (app / piece of software) that is responsible for this function?

The dialogue box that asks for which app to use.
    - complete action using:
    - choose an app:
    - open with:

Is it a package?
Can I disable it?

I know there is "open by default" and "app preferences"
Where you can set the default app to open automatically for some files, links, etc.

But sometimes the dialogue doesn't show up for certain actions. Like trying to upload a file on a specific browser doesn't prompt the dialogue but instead goes automatically to camera. Which is super weird.

Would appreciate any thread of info.

---

Edit:
Screenshot
"uploading file to Microsoft form using Google Chrome"

[image: "complete action with" screenshot]

Comment: It's an Android framework component: `android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity`. Related answers: https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A218526+Resolver+Activity

Comment: But e.g. in case of the image upload, an app does not have to use this framework component. The app can instead directly open a specific app.

Comment: Thanks Irfan for the answer and the link. I will read them well.

Comment: @Robert, ok so you mean choosing an app to open file or link uses that component. But uploading file it works like sending/sharing file and it directly chooses an app? I feel like I'm missing something. What decides which of the operations to happen?

Comment: @RooTenshi No I wrote the app developer can implement it this or that way.

Comment: @Robert, oh ok I see got it. I added an image in the question. Can you verify if it's from that component or not? That's if there is a way to tell visually like having "only once" choice in some dialogues.

Comment: The screenshot you've added is that of  `ResolverActivity` when it handles [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#open-file). // There's also a `android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity` which usually appears when the app uses [ShareSheet](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#why-to-use-system-sharesheet) instead of simple [Intent Resolver](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#using-android-intent-resolver). Share Sheet doesn't have "Just Once" and "Always" options.

Comment: Thanks again, Irfan. That was a great help! Now I understand more.